# External USB C Monitor not being recognised on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, usb

I'm having trouble analysing why this my Asus USB C monitor isn't working with Ubuntu 16.06.

```
andrew@leftovers:~$ lspci -d ::0c03 -k 
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
```

And some more debugging, no idea what I'm really looking for though.

```
andrew@leftovers:~$ tail -f /var/log/kern.log
Jun 19 20:25:13 leftovers kernel: [29072.376178] usb 1-3: new low-speed USB device number 27 using xhci_hcd
Jun 19 20:25:14 leftovers kernel: [29072.563646] usb 1-3: No LPM exit latency info found, disabling LPM.
Jun 19 20:25:14 leftovers kernel: [29072.564765] usb 1-3: config index 0 descriptor too short (expected 18, got 8)
Jun 19 20:25:14 leftovers kernel: [29072.564777] usb 1-3: invalid descriptor for config index 0: type = 0x2, length = 9
Jun 19 20:25:14 leftovers kernel: [29072.564785] usb 1-3: can't read configurations, error -22
Jun 19 20:25:14 leftovers kernel: [29072.732143] usb 1-3: new low-speed USB device number 28 using xhci_hcd
Jun 19 20:25:14 leftovers kernel: [29072.919652] usb 1-3: No LPM exit latency info found, disabling LPM.
Jun 19 20:25:14 leftovers kernel: [29072.924356] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0451, idProduct=ace1
Jun 19 20:25:14 leftovers kernel: [29072.924372] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jun 19 20:25:14 leftovers kernel: [29072.924382] usb 1-3: Product: TPS65982
Jun 19 20:25:14 leftovers kernel: [29072.924389] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Texas Instruments
Jun 19 20:25:14 leftovers kernel: [29072.924394] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: 0001.00.00
```

Comment: The `lcpci` output shows that you have a USB controller, but nothing about what's attached to the USB bus. Could you add the output of `lsusb` when the monitor is plugged-in?